# How to get frequency word with Solr after filtering word

Tags: solr, filtering, solrj, facet

I got a result about frequency word using facet in **Solrj**, but in the result list, it have a word which i don't or want to skip to count from the document.

E.g., in the document

```
word1 word2 word3 word4 word1 word2 word3
```

the result will be

```
word1 : 2
word2 : 2       
word3 : 1
```

like above. i want to get the result like

```
word1 : 2
word2 : 2   --> dont need to count.....i want to skip it
word3 : 1
```

I have a list kind of word list which i want to skip when counting word. Please help me with that

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to skip it in the front end code than doing it in Solr - unless you can reindex each time the list changes.

If you're just going to index once (or can reindex when the list changes), create a field by itself and have a stopword filter remove the terms you don't want in the specific field. The problem with this approach is that content already in the index won't change when you update the filter.